# Grouping two arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array "animalTypes" `[dog, dog, cat, cat, cat]` which contents changes dynamically (but always in this manner of grouping) and along with this, is another array of equal size, `[K9, hound, persian, siamese, sphinx]`, which is acquired on the same input but in the attribute "breeds" and always same grouping as "animalTypes".

so i got these var containers

```
var animal = {};
animal["type"] = [];
```

How do I iterate the array so we that will fill animal["type"] this way:

```
{
    type    : dog
    breeds  : K9, hound
},
{
    type    : cat
    breeds  : persian, siamese, sphinx
}`
```

So far I'm successfull in iterating the two arrays, but I need to group by above.

```
var animalTypesChecked = $('input[name="animalTypes"]:checked');
var animalTypesCheckedContainer = [];

$.each(animalTypesChecked, function(index,value){
    animalTypesCheckedContainer.push($(this).val());
});

var animalBreedsOfChecked = $('input[name="animalTypes"]:checked');
var animalBreedsOfCheckedcontainer = [];

$.each(animalBreedsOfChecked, function(){
    animalBreedsOfCheckedcontainer.push($(this).eq($(this).index()).attr('breeds'));
});
```

This is what I'm working on:

```
for(){
    animal.type.push({
        type : <animalType here>, 
        breeds : <animal breed here>
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML. `$(this).eq($(this).index())` does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build your desired object at the time you iterate over your checkboxes:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    // First create object keyed by types, which have the breeds array as values
    var breedsByType = {};
    $('input[name="animalTypes"]:checked').each(function() {
        var type = $(this).val();
        breedsByType[type] = breedsByType[type] || [];
        breedsByType[type].push($(this).attr('breeds'));
    });
    // Convert that object to an array of objects:  
    var result = $.map(breedsByType, function(breeds, type) {
        return {
            type: type,
            breeds: breeds
        };
    });
    console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="animalTypes" value="dog" breeds="K9" checked>Dog - K9<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animalTypes" value="dog" breeds="hound" checked>Dog - hound<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animalTypes" value="cat" breeds="persian" checked>Cat - persian<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animalTypes" value="cat" breeds="siamese" checked>Cat - siamese<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="animalTypes" value="cat" breeds="sphinx" checked>Cat - sphinx<br>
<button>Go</button>
```